# Eclipse : Find a line of text and replace it with two lines of text

Tags: regex, eclipse

In eclipse I want to replace a line of text

```
@author abc
```

with

```
@author abc
@version 1.0.0
```

its allowing only one line of text to replace an existing line of text.

How to do this!!

In other words I want to attach a second line to the first line.
I tried

```
@author abc\n@version 1.0.0
```

But its not working.

Basically I want to put some text on top of each method of every class in my project, how to do that.

Comment: Does any of the answers below answer your question? If yes, consider accepting the best one. BTW, you might need no regex at all, just replace `@author abc\r\n@version 1.0.0` with `@author abc @version 1.0.0` if you have two lines and want to put them on 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the box for Regular Expressions and then use \R instead of \n

Comment: What is the meaning of \R why should we use that. Its working for me though.

Comment: \R and \n have different meanings in regex, the former is a line delimeter, the latter is a new line. They get handled differently depending on the OS. For example, \n doesn't work on my windows machine but \R does because \R is independent of the platform. Here's an [article](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/09/some-useful-regular-expressions-for.html) that might help.

Comment: That's why the solution proposed by Maroun Maroun did not work for me. I am on windows. Thanks for elaborating the things.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy-paste the line as is (using your mouse), paste it in **Find**, enter whatever you want in **Replace With**, and it should work (don't worry about the weird ASCII characters you could probably see, Eclipse knows how to handle it for you).

If you want to use a regex, try this one (note the `.*` and the escaped dots):

```
@author abc\n.*@version 1\.0\.0 
             ↑↑          ↑  ↑
```

But don't forget to check the checkbox that "Regular expressions".

[image]

Comment: You are talking about ctrl + F thing. In that only I should paste.

Comment: @JohnDoe Indeed, that's the one I'm talking about. I edited my answer to work with regexes as well.

Comment: I am getting error Sir. \R is working for me but not the \n